# Use a variable as parameter in Set-MsolUser

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

Why can't I use a variable as a parameter in PowerShell?

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName john.doe@contoso.com -$parameter Stockholm
```

$parameter is equal to City in this case

```
Set-MsolUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-City'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName john.doe@contoso.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following options:

**1)Invoke the command with arguments**

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem} -ArgumentList "-$($para) C:\Temp"
```

**2) [Use splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)**

```
$Val = 'Path'
$HashArguments  = @{
    $Val = 'C:\Temp'
}

Get-ChildItem @HashArguments
```

Comment: Splatting is indeed the way to go; the first method fundamentally doesn't work: you can only pass _positional_ arguments via `-ArgumentList` (except to external programs) and, as an aside, you're not even referencing the arguments inside the script block. I suggest you remove the first solution. (The only thing you could do is variable-less splatting, such as `Invoke-Command { param($ht) Get-ChildItem @ht } -args  @{ Path = 'c:\temp' }` or, more simply, `& { param($ht) Get-ChildItem @ht } @{ Path = 'c:\temp' }`).